# ERC20 - How to split the initial token supply on multiple accounts?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, binance-smart-chain

Can someone explain to me why it's not possible to split the initial total supply with the Transfer event to multiple address that are not the _msgSender() address ?

The goal here is to "mint" with the 0x00 address the tokens on multiple wallets (12% in devs wallet, 5% in marketing wallet and 3% in another wallet) but directly in the constructor not using an external function that I will have to call in a script during the deployment.

But it's not working and I'm not getting any errors... Really don't understand

This is my code :

```
constructor () public payable{
    uint256 _tTotransfer = _tTotal;

    uint256 _tToDevs = (_tTotal.mul(12)).div(100);
    _tTotransfer = _tTotransfer.sub((_tTotal.mul(12)).div(100));

    uint256 _tToMarketing = (_tTotal.mul(5)).div(100);
    _tTotransfer = _tTotransfer.sub((_tTotal.mul(5)).div(100));

    uint256 _tToApes = (_tTotal.mul(3)).div(100);
    _tTotransfer = _tTotransfer.sub((_tTotal.mul(3)).div(100));

    _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;

    emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotransfer); 
    emit Transfer(address(0), _devsWallet, _tToDevs); 
    emit Transfer(address(0), _marketingWallet, _tToMarketing); 
    emit Transfer(address(0), _apesWallet, _tToApes);
    
}
```

Also I don't understand why it's not possible to directly "mint" the total supply on another wallet (not to split but the entire) than the _msgSender.

Thx guys hope someone would help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `_rOwned` holds the actual token balance of each address:

You're correctly emitting the `Transfer` events, but need to update the token balances as well.

---

This line sets the `_msgSender()` balance to `_tTotal`, which you don't want according to your description.

```
_rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal; // incorrect
```

You want them to have the remaining `_tTotransfer`.

---

And the same goes for other initial owners

```
_rOwned[_msgSender()] = _tTotransfer; // replace the above line to this
emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotransfer);

_rOwned[_devsWallet] = _tToDevs;
emit Transfer(address(0), _devsWallet, _tToDevs);

rOwned[_marketingWallet] = _tToMarketing;
emit Transfer(address(0), _marketingWallet, _tToMarketing);

rOwned[_apesWallet] = _tToApes;
emit Transfer(address(0), _apesWallet, _tToApes);
```

Comment: You helped me to understood how it works! Thank you so much !!